# Angular read array from ActivatedRoute params

Tags: angular

I am observing what looks like an inconsistent format when reading ActivatedRoute params.

- when the component is first reached with an array of parameters in the url (`localhost:1/a;t=1,2`), `params['t']` comes out as a string: `'1,2'`
- when navigating programmatically via the router later, the same kind of url is produced (`localhost:1/a;t=1,2`), but now `params['t']` is an array of numbers `[1, 2]`

In both cases the params are obtained via the same subscription, done at init:

```js
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      console.info(JSON.stringify(params)),
  });
}

// if needs be, here's how I perform the programmatic navigation
this.router.navigate(['.', {t:[1,2]}], {relativeTo: this.route})
```

Of course I can check the type of the params I get and convert before using, but it seems a bit ugly. Is this something known or am I missing something ?